# Unfortunately (app installed from Google Play) has stopped

Tags: android, google-play

I have little time to fix this so I decided to ask a question here.

I developed an Android app in Android Studio using [Parse.com](http://parse.com) as backend. I tried it on different devices before publishing it to make sure everything worked.

However, once I published it to the Google Play Store, I downloaded it from there and got the error “Unfortunately (app) has stopped”.

Is there any way to know what's happening? Since it's a published app there's no Logcat or specific information on why it crashed. It' frustrating.

Thanks.

Comment: If the device enables error reporting, you can view the crash log & information in Google Play Developer Console

Answer (score 3):

If the app has crashed, you should be able to submit a crash report which you can then see in the Google Play Developer Console under Crashes & ANRs. There you will be able to see some device info and the stack trace.

Alternatively, you can integrate a crash reporting library (there are many really, BugSense, Crashlytics, etc.)
The advantage of these libraries is that users don't have to actively submit the crash reports, but the libraries collect and send the data automatically.